# tiny_tds error on heroku connecting to SqlServer db

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using the tiny_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gems to connect to a remote sqlserver database.  I have it working locally but when I deploy to heroku I get the following error.

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.**

Is there setup needed on heroku to get this working?

Comment: Are you trying to send Unicode characters to your SQL Server?  Have you tried enforcing a friendlier encoding such as ASCII to see if that works?

Comment: I'm just doing TableName.first, and I get that error.  When I run it locally and change my database.yml file to point to the same db it works fine.

Comment: @Scott: How did you manage to get tiny_tds works with Heroku? Are you using the Cedar Stack ? Many thanks...

Comment: Heroku has FreeTDS 0.82 installed on Bamboo, so you should be able to get it working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging and trial and error, the root cause is from ntext(max) and nvarchar(max) columns.  Once the columns were changed to varchar it worked.

If you ever need to know the difference, it is that nvarchar takes up twice the space of varchar because it allows for non-English Unicode characters. You basically only need this if you wil be storing data in other languages.